# Variable in renderer(_:didAdd:for:) not updating

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, coreml

I am working on a IPhone app that uses CoreML and ARKit simultaneously. The CoreML is supposed to recognize a number and the ARKit should detect a vertical plane (aka wall) and add some planes over that same wall with the content displayed on those planes depending on the recognised number.
So, the CoreML is working 100%. Everytime I "change" the number the `topPrediction` variable updates automatically ( so far so good ). The thing is that my variable in `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor` does not update! What I mean is that the first number recognized by the CoreML is correctly sent to the renderer func and it works like a charm but if I turn the camera to another number it stills assumes that it's the first number! As you may see in the code, I even tried making a `func getGabNum() -> Int` and then calling it in the `renderer` func ( `var num = getGabNum()` ) but I continue getting the warning "Variable 'num' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant" which means that something is not right. So guys, here is my code! Hope you can help me and thank you!

```
struct Room : Decodable {
let id : Int?
let num : Int?
//Adicionar Schedules
var horario = [Schedule]()
}

struct Schedule : Decodable  {
let id : Int?
let hora_ini : Date?
let hora_fim : Date?
let descr : String?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case hora_ini
    case hora_fim
    case descr
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var debugLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var debugTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!

let dispatchQueueML = DispatchQueue(label: "com.hw.dispatchqueueml") // A Serial Queue
var visionRequests = [VNRequest]()

var room: Room?
var room_array: [[Int]] = [[17, 0], [43, 0], [120,0]]
var teste = 0
var num = -1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    let scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.scene = scene
    configureLighting()

    guard let selectedModel = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: SalasMLv6().model) else {
        fatalError("Could not load model.")
    }

    let classificationRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: selectedModel, completionHandler: classificationCompleteHandler)
    classificationRequest.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOption.centerCrop // Crop from centre of images and scale to appropriate size.
    visionRequests = [classificationRequest]
    loopCoreMLUpdate()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setUpSceneView()
}

func setUpSceneView()
{
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = .vertical
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    sceneView.session.pause()
}

func configureLighting()
{
    sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Do any desired updates to SceneKit here.
    }
}

func loopCoreMLUpdate() {
    dispatchQueueML.async {
        self.updateCoreML()
        self.loopCoreMLUpdate()
    }
}

func updateCoreML() {
    // Get Camera Image as RGB
    let pixbuff : CVPixelBuffer? = (sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage)
    if pixbuff == nil { return }
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixbuff!)

    // Prepare CoreML/Vision Request
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, options: [:])

    // Run Vision Image Request
    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.visionRequests)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func classificationCompleteHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    // Catch Errors
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: " + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        return
    }
    guard let observations = request.results else {
        print("No results")
        return
    }

    // Get Classifications
    let classifications = observations[0...2] // top 3 results
        .compactMap({ $0 as? VNClassificationObservation })
        .map({ "\($0.identifier) \(String(format:" : %.2f", $0.confidence))" })
        .joined(separator: "\n")

    // Render Classifications
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        // Display Debug Text on screen
        self.debugTextView.text = "TOP 3 PROBABILITIES: \n" + classifications

        // Display Top Symbol
        var symbol = "❌"
        var gabNum: Int?
        let topPrediction = classifications.components(separatedBy: "\n")[0]
        let topPredictionName = topPrediction.components(separatedBy: ":")[0].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

        // Only display a prediction if confidence is above 90%
        let topPredictionScore:Float? = Float(topPrediction.components(separatedBy: ":")[1].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
        if (topPredictionScore != nil && topPredictionScore! > 0.05) {
            if (topPredictionName == "120") {
                symbol = "1️⃣2️⃣0️⃣"
                gabNum = 120
                self.teste = gabNum!
                }
            if (topPredictionName == "43") {
                symbol = "4️⃣3️⃣"
                gabNum = 43
                self.teste = gabNum!
            }
            if (topPredictionName == "17") {
                symbol = "1️⃣7️⃣"
                gabNum = 17
                self.teste = gabNum!
            }
        }

        if let gn = gabNum {
            // get room from REST
            let jsonURL = "someURL\(gn)"
            guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else {
                return
            }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print("error)")
                    return
                }
                do {
                    self.room = try JSONDecoder().decode(Room.self, from: data!)
                }catch{
                    print(“Decoder Error”)
                }
                }.resume()
        }
        self.debugLabel.text = symbol
    }
}

// MARK: - HIDE STATUS BAR
   override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool { return true }

func getGabNum() -> Int {
    return self.teste
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
{
    guard room != nil else  {
        print("room == nil")
        return
    }

    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else {
        return
    }

    num = getGabNum()

    if( num == room_array[0][0] && room_array[0][1] == 1 ){
        return
    }else{
        if( num == room_array[1][0] && room_array[1][1] == 1 ){
            return
        }else{
            if( num == room_array[2][0] && room_array[2][1] == 1 ){
                return
            }else{
                var i = 0
                for horario in (self.room?.horario)!{
                // Planes and Nodes Stuff Right Here
                }
                switch self.room?.num{
                case 17: room_array[0][1] = 1
                case 43: room_array[1][1] = 1
                case 120:room_array[2][1] = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Change var num to let num = getGabNum() because you are just setting it once and then never altering it again

Comment: @JoshRobbins That's exactly the problem. I want to keep changing it! I want num be always the same as gabNum so that i can display the right content.

Comment: Declare var num under other variables e.g under var teste = 0 not within the function

Comment: @JoshRobbins Thanks! I just did what you said (already edited the code, can you check if that's it? ) and now it changes! What happens now is that when I change the number , the num variable does change but the planes are not displayed. I need to detect another wall and only then the plane appears while it was supposed to appear where the number was. This is my guess but I think that when I recognise the number there is already a new PlaneAnchor over the number so I have to find a new one so that the plane is shown. Any idea on how to solve this one?